# How can I make and train custom-dataset in my own dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have questions on my work.

I build a multiclass classification model that classifies an input image as one label of 4 classes.

Currently, I have 100,000 images that are made up 4 classes imbalanced. And I also have csv file including information of file name, class, path. I made a csv file using Pandas library.

Now given my computing power, I wanna just test only 20,000 images. For sure, those 20,000 images should have images of 4 classes as same ratio.

In my opinion, it will be good to use info of my csv file by class. But my problem is that I have no idea how to flesh out my thinking. So I need your guys tips.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I didn't know how to explain my problem... but I try to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found, although it might not be the most optimal one. Assuming that you have 5,000 images for each class.
If you have a dataframe (your csv file) that is structured as follows:

```py
>>> df

       filename  class
0       one.png      1
1       two.png      2
.
.
.
99,000 name.png     4
```

You can then get a subdataframe with

```py
subdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
class_names = df['class'].unique()
n_to_sample = 20,000/len(class_names)

for class_name in class_names:
    subdf = pd.concat([subdf,df[df['class']==class_name].sample(n=n_to_sample)])
```

Hope this worked!

Comment: Oh, I really appreciate your help. I'm gonna try your solution right now:) And then I tried another code using query() and sample() function of Pandas library! It also works!

Comment: In detail, I apply query() and sample(frac=0.2) functions, yeah, a 'frac' parameter doesn't return just 20,000 images. But I need same ratio as the original dataset imbalanced. So I can utilize your resolutions when I need same ratio data every labels. Anyway thank you soooo much!